# Javascript table using data from multiple txt files and displaying on html file

Tags: javascript, arrays, text, file-io, datatable

I developed a code to read data of user ratings (from multiple txt files say more than two txt files) and display them in table.  I have trouble properly displaying table and data and so far I managed to access only one txt file at a time.  Any suggestions on fixing the table layout (added another table to show how it should look like) and data arrangement in the table.  Below is my sample txt data files called sample1.txt and sample2.txt and then complete html code with javascript within in.

sample1.txt

```
 user1  100
 user2  80
 user3  60
 user4  75
 user5  100
 user6  80
 user7  60
 user8  75
 user9  12
 user10 13
```

sample2.txt

```
 user1  10
 user2  20
 user3  30
 user4  45
 user5  50
 user6  60
 user7  70
 user8  80
 user9  90
 user10 99
```

tableExample4.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
  <title>Read Text File</title> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
  <input type="file" name="inputfile"
        id="inputfile"> 
  <br> 

  <pre id="output"></pre> 
  <script>

  var file = document.getElementById('inputfile');

  file.addEventListener('change', () => {
  var txtArr = [];
  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function() {
    // By lines
    var lines = this.result.split('\n');
    for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
        txtArr = [...txtArr, ...(lines[line].split(" "))];
    }
   }

   fr.onloadend = function() {
    //console.log(txtArr);
   // document.getElementById('output').textContent=txtArr.join("");
   // document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = txtArr; 
   // console.log(txtArr[1]);
   
   // *********************  table 1 code test ****************************************

    var table= document.createElement('table'),
        thead = document.createElement('thead'),
        tbody = document.createElement('tbody'),
        th,
        tr,
        td;
        th = document.createElement('th'),          
        th.innerHTML="Name";
        table.appendChild(th);
        th = document.createElement('th'); 
        th.innerHTML= "Sample1";
        table.appendChild(th);
        th = document.createElement('th'); 
        th.innerHTML= "Sample2"
        table.appendChild(th);
        table.appendChild(thead);            
        table.appendChild(tbody);
        
        document.body.appendChild(table);
     for(var i=0;i<txtArr.length;i++){
        tr = document.createElement('tr'),
        //for Name
        td= document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML=txtArr[i];
        tr.appendChild(td);

        //for Samples
        td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML=txtArr[i];
        tr.appendChild(td);
          tbody.appendChild(tr);
     }
   // ******************  end of test code *************************************


    }

    fr.readAsText(file.files[0]);


    })
    // *********************  table 2 code test ****************************************
   function generate_table() {
   // get the reference for the body
   var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

   // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
   var tbl = document.createElement("table");
   var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

   // creating all cells
   for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   // creates a table row
   var row = document.createElement("tr");

   for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
   // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
   // node the contents of the <td>, and put the <td> at
   // the end of the table row
   var cell = document.createElement("td");
   var cellText = document.createTextNode("cell in row "+i+", column ");
   cell.appendChild(cellText);
   row.appendChild(cell);
   }

   // add the row to the end of the table body
  tblBody.appendChild(row);
  } 

  // put the <tbody> in the <table>
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  // appends <table> into <body>
  body.appendChild(tbl);
  // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
  tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");

  }


  // ******************  end of test code ******************************************

  </script>

  <input type="button" value="Generate a table." onclick="generate_table()">

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent added the table header and the input files need to have no spaces before the first field and only one space between first and second field as below.

Select One File then the next then when all selected use create. This draws the table and wipes the data array for a new selection.

Sample1.txt

```
user1 100
user2 80
user3 60
user4 75
user5 100
user6 80
user7 60
user8 75
user9 12
user10 13
```

Sample2.txt

```
user1 10
user2 20
user3 30
user4 45
user5 50
user6 60
user7 70
user8 80
user9 90
user10 99
```

New Script as follows

```
var file = document.getElementById('inputfile');

var txtArr = [];

file.addEventListener('change', () => {

  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function() {
    // By lines
    var lines = this.result.split('\n');
    for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
        txtArr.push(lines[line].split(" "));
    }
   }
fr.readAsText(file.files[0]);
});
    
function generate_table() {
   if ( typeof(document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]) !="undefined" ) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].remove();
   }
   // get the reference for the body
   var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    
   // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
   var tbl = document.createElement("table");
   var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
   
    // creating all cells
    for (var i = 0; i < txtArr.length; i++) {
       // creates a table row
       var row = document.createElement("tr");
           for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                var cellText = document.createTextNode(txtArr[i][j]);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
                tblBody.appendChild(row);
     } 
      
     // put the <tbody> in the <table>
     tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
     // appends <table> into <body>
     body.appendChild(tbl);
     // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
     tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
     
    }
    txtArr=[];
}
```